# JavaScript Closure changing variable value from the outer scope

Tags: javascript, function, closures, lexical-scope, lexical-closures

I don't understand why my returned function didn't change the value of the variable from the outer function.

Hi, I wrote js function:

```
function num() {
    let number = 0;
    console.log(number)
    return function() {
        return number++
    }
}
```

then run it once. `let add = num()`
After that I run `add()` multiple times and it returned my number variable with new values, but when I decided to run `num()` function, in the console it would still return 0, as value of number. and I don't understand why this happens, because isn't returned function changing the value of number?

Comment: Every time you invoke the `num()` function, a new closure with a new variable `number` and a new return function is created.

Answer (score 2):

> when I decided to run num() function, in the console it would still return 0, as value of number

Well, yes.  Let's take a look at the first two lines of code executed any time you invoke the `num()` function:

```
let number = 0;
console.log(number)
```

There is no scenario in which those two lines of code would ever log anything but `0` to the console.

It sounds like you wanted to declare `number` in a higher scope.  For example:

```
let number = 0;

function num() {
  console.log(number);

  return function() {
    return number++;
  };
}
```

Then any calls to `num()` (or the function it returns) will use the same global `number` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the value of the number variable in the `num()` function does not change is because the number variable is a `local variable` to the `num()` function, and the returned function created by `num()` has access to this variable due to closure.

When you call `num()`, a `new number` variable with an initial value of `0` is created. Then, the function returns another function that has access to the number variable through closure. This returned function increments the value of number every time it is called and returns the new value.

So when you assign the returned function to the `add` variable and call it multiple times, the value of the number variable within the closure is incremented and returned each time. However, when you call num() again, a new `number` variable with an initial value of 0 is created again, and the old value of number is not affected.

If you want to change the value of number in the num() function, you can modify the code by setting `number` variable at `global scope` or outside of the `num()` function.

```js
let number = 0;
function num() {
  console.log(number)
  return function() {
      return number++
  }
}

let add = num() // 0 
add()
add()
add()

num() // 3
```